# React Ag-grid remote filtering does not preserve filter selection

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm using ag-grid with its remote mode, and it is all mostly working fine except that the filters do not remain toggled off when selected.

DEMO: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/Wl6Qq1OYC63CpuUf If you filter the athletes' column you will see the bug I have. If you pick one, it does the query, but the checkbox remains selected.

I've search intensively in the documentation, but I see no mention of how I should manage the filters. I've tried using the `.getFilterInstance()` method to set the filter, but that does not work either.

Also there's [this closed issue](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/1148), but people keep asking about a working example of something similar but no-one has provided one.

What am I missing?